# MongoDB Start several mongod with different ports

Tags: mongodb

I can't change port in second mongod in my cmd
1 I'm starting mongod in c:\mongodb\bin
2 I'm starting cmd and writing

```
  cd c:\mongodb\bin
    mongod --port 10003
```

But second mongod not work.
Help me.Thank you!

This is error what show me

```
C:\Windows\system32> cd c:\mongodb\bin

c:\mongodb\bin>mongod --port 10003
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.619
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.620 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by
 default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.622
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.635 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8240 port=10003 d
bpath=\data\db\ 32-bit host=Danil
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.637 [initandlisten]
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.638 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary
.
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.640 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to le
ss than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.641 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults t
o off for 32 bit and is currently off.
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.643 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/c
ore/32bit
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.645 [initandlisten]
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.646 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.10
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.648 [initandlisten] git version: e3d78955d181e475345ebd60053
a4738a4c5268a
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.650 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversio
n(major=6, minor=0, build=6002, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 2') BOOST
_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.651 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.653 [initandlisten] options: { port: 10003 }
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.655 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13627 Unable
 to create/open lock file: \data\db\mongod.lock ??????? ?? ????? ???????? ??????
 ? ?????, ??? ??? ???? ???? ????? ?????? ?????????.. Is a mongod instance alread
y running?, terminating
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.657 dbexit:
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.658 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening socke
ts...
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.660 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.662 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.663 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...

Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.665 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.666 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Wed Apr 16 22:15:56.668 dbexit: really exiting now

c:\mongodb\bin>
```

Comment: what's the error message you are getting?

Comment: Are you starting them in the same directory?

Comment: the second instance of mongod will require a different db path (than the default which is being used by the first instance).  so, you'll have to create a different data folder and specify that when starting the second instance using `--dbpath`

Comment: Check my earlier comment about `--dbpath`.  That's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start multiple MongoDB processes on the same database.

What you need to do is:

```
mongod --dbpath c:\database1 --port 27017
mongod --dbpath c:\database2 --port 27018
```

Remember that you must manually create the database folders.

Usually if you read carefully the error log you will find the problem:

"13627 Unable to create/open lock file: \data\db\mongod.lock.
Is a mongod instance already running?"

Answer (score 1):

try to start mongod with admin option as it is not able to open the file mongod.lock

Comment: Your answer is good, please add more detail on how to start mongod with admin right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).